# I don't understand this case of recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is a solution from this [exercice](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/use-recursion-to-create-a-countdown) on FreeCodeCamp

```
function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const arr = countdown(n - 1);
    arr.unshift(n);
    return arr;
  }
}
```

I understand the concept of recursion. I get that the function countdown will be repeated until n < 1 and the following command arr.unshift(n) will be executed once all possible values of n will be evaluated. What bugs me is that I don't get when or how const arr becomes and array.

Comment: In the base case, `countdown` returns the empty array literal `[]`. This is what will get assigned to `arr`.

Comment: "I understand the concept of recursion."  Not to be rude, but given what you are stuck on, I'd argue that you *don't* understand the concept very well.  Hint: what does countdown return especially in the if block

Answer (score 0):

> What bugs me is that I don't get when or how const arr becomes and
>   array.

See the base case returns an empty array? This is where it all starts, thanks to that you are able to proceed with the array structure once the code returns from the recursive calls.

**Code explanation**

Unshift will append at zeroth index the LIFO, meaning

the last which was in is 1 and it will be added to the array, after that the array will add number 2 at zeroth index and at second index you'll have number 1, after that number 3 will be added at zeroth index, second index will be number 2, and last index will contain number 1. Now you see the pattern...

Try to console.log in between

```
function countDown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countDown(n - 1);
    console.log(n)
    countArray.unshift(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countDown(5));
```

If you are more used to ES6+ syntax, add the first element n at the first position of the array and de-structure the rest.

```
function countDown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray=[n,...countDown(n - 1)];
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countDown(5));
```

And at last, you can make it a one liner with ternary operators:

```
const countDown = (n) => n < 1 ? [] : [n, ...countDown(n - 1)];
console.log(countDown(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the pattern for a relatively simple call. Here again is the function:

```
function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const arr = countdown(n - 1);
    arr.unshift(n);
    return arr;
  }
}
```

Say you call `countdown(2)`:

#### Loop 1:

1a) n is not less than 1

1b) an arr is initialized and set to countdown(1)

#### Loop 2:

2a) n is not less than 1

2b) an arr is initialized and set to countdown(0)

#### Loop 3:

3a) n is less than 1

3b) an empty array is returned to loop 2

> arr is []

#### Loop 2 cont.

2c) arr.unshift adds the number 2 to the start of the array.

> arr is [2]

2d) arr is returned to loop 1

#### Loop 1 cont.

1c) arr.unshift adds the number 1 to the start of the array.

> array is [1,2]

1d) arr is returned to function call

So if you wrote `let result = countdown(2)` and `console.log(result)`, you will get: `[1,2]`

> What bugs me is that I don't get when or how const arr becomes and
>   array.

Look at steps 3b, 2b, and 2c:

`3b) an empty array is returned to loop 2`

`2b) an arr is initialized and set to countdown(0)`

`2c) arr.unshift adds the number 2 to the start of the array.`

An empty array is set to `const arr`, then the number 2 is added to that array.

Now look at steps 2d and 1c:

`2d) arr is returned to loop 1`

`1c) arr.unshift adds the number 1 to the start of the array.`

That array is set to a **new** array like this (`const arr = [2]`) and the number 1 is added to that array. Finally in 1d, that new array is returned to the expression that called the function. For every recursive loop you have something like this:

`const arr = something`

`new const arr = old const arr`

Comment: Thanks for detailing the loop. Makes it clearer but the one detail that bugs me is: arr is [] at the 3rd loop. I know that the function will eventually return an empty array but I don't know why this empty array is assigned to arr.

Comment: @xgreed Did you see my update at the end that I made a few minutes ago? I go over that a bit.

Comment: countdown(2) => const arr = countdown(1) => const arr = countdown(0) => return []. countdown(0) returns an empty array that is assigned to arr and once that "loop" ends, countdown(1) arr.unshift adds 1 to arr and .....

Comment: @xgreed Yes, exactly